# How to write unit tests for some a class such as the timer class?

Tags: c++, unit-testing

Let's say I just wrote the following class and I am starting to write some unit tests for it:

http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/classOgre_1_1Timer.html

How would I make sure the timer is working properly by just the unit tests? I can test to make sure that `getMilliseconds()` is always greater than the start time for example, but that does not tell me that `getMilliseconds()` is returning the correct delta-time.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, you should separate out the OS call and make that it's own class that uses virtual functions so you can stub out the OS call with your own data. That would let you test that everything except for the data you get back from the OS is correct.

In my opinion, this is good idea in general. I have come to think of the OS as the Singleton you can't remove. It's best to localize the way you use that Singleton so that most of your code doesn't access it.

That being said, there are some techniques for testing the OS.

One technique for testing is to try to get the OS to do approximately the same thing in two different ways and make sure those two different ways more or less match up. In this case, I would suggest using a `sleep` function of some sort. On Unix, for example, you could use `nanosleep` to sleep for a fraction of a second and then test to make sure that your timer class measured that fraction of a second as being more or less the same (within some margin of error).

Comment: Using sleep() with a few tricks, I managed to unit test my timer ok(not to a very precise though)...

Answer (score 2):

The core thought of a unit test is controlling the input to check that the output behaves as desired.

Here, you would (somehow) need to control the clock that gives the class its time reference to be able to properly unit test it.

Failing that, you will have to settle for approximate results, and even worse you might end up be platform dependent for OSes have various ways of measuring time. Still, it might be good enough.

An example: if you have access to a clock, you can checks things like intervals:

```
outerStart = refClock.time();
start = timer.time();
innerStart = refClock.time();

// ... 

innerEnd = refClock.time();
end = timer.time();
outerEnd = refClock.time();
```

Then, you should have outerEnd - outerStart > end - start > innerEnd - innerStart, though with time you might have time resolution issues (like the clock being too imprecise).

Comment: The issues you raised is what went through my mind and the example is similar to what I thought of but the potential of the test failing due to approximation is high imo which will make unit tests like this a pain during builds. But +1 for the example as it is more likely the one I may use if there is no solution.

Answer (score 2):

**You probably wouldn't unit test the real time is accurate**.  If you wrote that class you are probably making some calls to OS-specific functions that return the clock time.  You would test that by checking that it gives reasonable-seeming responses on each OS.

**You can unit test any logic** such as time conversions you have within the test by stubbing out the calls to the OS and returning values you control.